# getting data from multiple SQl Server tables into one format

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The data I am working with is as follows:

Assembled Table:

```
Name  Qty 
XXXX   5
YYYY   3
ZZZZ   2
```

Stock_Table

```
Part_Name  Qty
AAAA        5
BBBB        10
CCCC        20
1111        55
2222        35
```

Individual_Parts_Table

```
Name  Part_Name 
XXXX   AAAA     
XXXX   BBBB    
XXXX   CCCC
```

Substitutes_Table

```
Part_Name Sub_Name
AAAA       1111
AAAA       2222
AAAA       3333
BBBB       4444
BBBB       5555
CCCC       6666
```

Now in my final output I want it to look like the following format:

Final_Table

```
Name   Part_Name  Qty
XXXX   AAAA        
XXXX   BBBB    
XXXX   CCCC  
XXXX   1111
XXXX   2222
XXXX   3333
XXXX   4444
XXXX   5555
XXXX   6666
```

I have a feeling it is possible using JOIN but if someone could guide the way it would be most helpful as I am not able to finalize on a plan for this.

THank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to figure out what you are doing exactly but yes a series of joins is all you need. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ If you find that understanding joins is not enough then you should probably take a look at this article for your next step. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You want one result record per name (part name or sub part name). You want one column that is always XXXX and another that contains the name and a third that contains always NULL. Yes?

Comment: Yes Thorsten. That is exactly the format i want. But the quantity in the quantity column should be the quantoty of the part in each line.

Comment: The quantity from STOCK_TABLE?

Comment: Hi Sean, yes I felt that it was a bit awkward the way I posed the question. But that link looks good....will read through it and make sure the next time an SQL Server question comes up, it will be my guide

Comment: Hello Thorsten, Yes the qwuantity from STOCK_TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

The part name is all names you find in substitutes_table, i.e. both part_name and sub_name. You get these with a UNION query. Then select the constant 'XXXX' with them and pick the quantity from the stock_table in a subquery. No join needed here.

```
select 
  'XXXX' as name, 
  part_name, 
  (
    select s.qty
    from stock_table s
    where s.part_name = names.part_name
  ) as qty
from
(
  select part_name from substitutes_table
  union
  select sub_name from substitutes_table
) names;
```

Instead of the subquery in the select clause you could also outer-join the stock table:

```
select 
  'XXXX' as name, 
  part_name, 
  s.qty
from
(
  select part_name from substitutes_table
  union
  select sub_name from substitutes_table
) names
left outer join stock_table s on s.part_name = names.part_name;
```

Comment: Hello Thorsten, thanks a ton for the answer. It looks like it will solve my query but I need to test it. One more thing, instead of hardcoding the XXXX, can i just pull the list from the Assembled table?

Comment: Well, you *could* somehow. But then you would probably write a complete different query. This is why I asked whether you only wanted to show XXXX combined with all names, which you answered with yes. If you want to query the related tables instead you would have to explain how they are related exactly and what precisely you want to select.